# Validar arreglo de inputs tipo checkbox con jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Actualmente tengo un lista que valores que muestro dentro de un formulario

```
<?php $index = 1;
        foreach ($ventas as $key => $value) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?= $index ?>" name="listaProductos[]" > <?php echo $value->codigo_farmacia; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="codFarmacia[]" value="<?= $value->codigo_farmacia; ?>">
<?php}?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Enviar solicitud</button>


//en jquery tengo lo siguiente 
    <script>
    $("#solicitud-form").on("submit", function () {
    event.preventDefault();

     var listaProductos = [];  

     $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(  function (i) {
        listaProductos[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    $("[name='prodCodigo[]']").each(function (i) {
    prodCodigo[i] = $(this).val();
    
});

</script>
```

y pues al darle enviar se envía el arreglo lleno debería solo contener los valores que están seleccionados, es decir validar con los valores las filas que están seleccionadas con el checkbox
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: diria que no te hace falta que hagas nada con el javascript para leerte eso en PHP, ya deberias recibirlo correctamente.  Pero no has puesto el PHP que lo recibe en la pregunta y así no es posible ayudarte mejor. Por otra parte, si insistes en usar javascript, o bien el fallo está en la sintaxis del evento on submit, que no terminas con `})` y debe estar dándote un error de javascript y no lo ves (y el formulario de ese modo se envia tal cual) o bien que después de eso no envias el formulario pues hacer un preventDefault() y despues de asignar la variable listaProductos no haces nada con ella

Comment: estoy resumiendo codigo bro, ya que esto pues lo envio directamente a una api, que no manejo

Comment: Pues con lo que has puesto antes a mi me funciona bien: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanhLdq/

Comment: Pero lo que has puesto ahora tiene menos sentido, pues esto `<input type="hidden" name="codFarmacia[]" value="<?= $value->codigo_farmacia; ?>">` no se que haces con el después, ni tampoco sabemos que es `$("[name='prodCodigo[]']")`.  Recuerda que aquí solo vemos lo que nos muestras, y no podemos adivinar lo que tu estás viendo. Recuerda hacer un [example] correcto para recibir mejor ayuda, gracias

Comment: si perdon, como se ve en la primera parte yo tengo una lista de productos donde ese input oculto es el codigo del producto y al enviarlo el jquery valida toda lista cargada. quisiera es validar las posiciones con la lista anterior, la lista de productos.

Comment: Lo siento, @Enrique, mientras no tengamos un [example] correcto que podamos reproducir tu pregunta no es completa y, al menos a mi, me es imposible intentar ayudarte más ni imaginarme correctamente lo que tu ves.